# Tool for editing docx document with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any tool / library for editing Docx file with javascript?

In my case i want to upload docx document with input of type 'file', edit this file with values from my input of type 'text', click button download and download edited Docx file.
Im using react.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: On basis upon what selection inside doc file you want to edit ?
Doc file can have any kind of content right so basic upon what you want to edit OR you want to open that file then edit manually ?

Comment: @Sanjay i upload templated docx file which content is always the same, it is like an empty form, then i need to fill this form with values from my inputs and then download edited file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Evgeniy

Best solution for your problem is to convert doc file into HTML file via:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/word-to-html

OR just create HTML file by yourself as it is fixed form file and add variables in HTML file just like we send mail templates and then just set values on those variables.

Finally convert HTML file to Word: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-docx

I hope this will solve your problem.
Just be remember to do all this process in background or async request to that nothing will block at user end.

Thanks